# Inject HttpServletRequest into rest service

Tags: java, rest, servlets, cxf

I want ot inject HttpServletRequest into my service via `@Context` annotation.
Here is my example:

```
@Path("/")
public class MyService {
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;
}
```

I use Apache CXF implementation and here are my dependencies from pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also I use Apache Karaf OSGI container for deploying and that's why my app is a bundle packaging type. There is configuration for that:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Import-Package>
                !*,
                javax.ws.rs,
                javax.ws.rs.core,
                javax.ws.rs.ext,
                org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.tl,
            </Import-Package>
            <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Without `javax.ws.rs.ext` and `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.tl` in import-package section I got one of these exceptions:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers is not visible from class loader 

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.tl.ThreadLocalProxy is not visible from class loader
```

**So now I have a follow exception when try to deploy my app:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest field MyService.request to org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.tl.ThreadLocalHttpServletRequest
```

And I spent a lot of time to figure out what's the problem..
**But one thing I note:**

if I use `ThreadLocalHttpServletRequest request` 
instead of `HttpServletRequest request`, then it works without exceptions, but the `request` field is `null` when I try to use it from any methods.

What should I do to make it works properly with `HttpServletReqest` ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext;



// your code goes like this
@Context 
private MessageContext context;



// try to get the request/response/session etc in your methods
HttpServletRequest req = context.getHttpServletRequest();
HttpServletResponse res = context.getHttpServletResponse()
```

Comment: It's deployed, but then I get `LinkageError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest`

Comment: I think, you are referring to wrong jars, please remove any server-specific libraries jars inside WEB-INF/lib something like servlet-api.jar , jsp-api.jar

Comment: I do not have WEB-INF directory, it is osgi bundle for apache-karaf container. Here is my related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53309483/java-lang-linkageerror-loader-constraint-violation-previously-initiated-for-a)

Comment: excluding these libraries from ur dependency something like this <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-webmvc"
        rev="4.0.4.RELEASE">
        <exclude org="javax.servlet" name="javax.servlet-api" />
        <exclude org="javax.servlet.jsp" name="jsp-api" />
        <exclude org="javax.el" name="javax.el-api" />
    </dependency>